# When I try to use my Json it shows only the first value (title) Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

There is part of my Json,

```
{
    pontos =     (
                {
            Id = 1;
            Latitude = "-22.739";
            Longitude = "-47.335";
            cidade = Americana;
            endereco = "RUA WASHINGTON LUIZ, 742, CENTRO, Americana/SP";
            letra = "letter-A";
            localizacao = "https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir//Quinoa+Natural+-+Washington+Luiz,+742+-+Centro,+Americana+-+SP,+13465-520/@-22.7399455,-47.3349734,19.5z/data=!4m15!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0xa4eca82f1081bbd9!2sQuinoa+Natural!8m2!3d-22.739908!4d-47.3353712!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x94";
            nome = "QUINOA NATURAL";
            site = "WWW.QUINOANATURAL.COM.BR";
            telefone = "(19) 3405-6006";
        },
                {
            Id = 2;
            Latitude = "-22.752";
            Longitude = "-47.345";
            cidade = Americana;
            endereco = "AV. BRASIL, 1740, VILA FREZZARIN, Americana/SP";
            letra = "letter-A";
            localizacao = "https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir//Av.+Brasil+Norte,+1740+-+Vila+Frezzarin,+Americana+-+SP/@-22.7522934,-47.3479628,17z/data=!4m13!1m4!3m3!1s0x94c89bd929bbb37d:0x97700c95cf048c5d!2sAv.+Brasil+Norte,+1740+-+Vila+Frezzarin,+Americana+-+SP!3b1!4m7!1m0!1m5!1";
            nome = "TERRANUTRA ORG\U00c2NICOS";
            site = "";
            telefone = "(19) 3408-0032";
        },
```

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    int test = 40;
    UIScrollView *sView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:sView];
    //http://blessing.com.br/aplicativos/pontos.php
    //http://api.iospond.com/api/index.php/GetData
    //setting the json as data
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blessing.com.br/aplicativos/pontos.php"]];
    NSError *error=nil;
    //Encoding the data to string
    NSString *teste = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //show the code json

    //putting the json in an arraylist
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[teste dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error ];
    CGFloat xPos = 0;
    CGFloat x = 0;
    CGFloat y = 10;
    CGFloat yPos = 10;
    for (NSDictionary *dic in json) {
        //show Ids catched in the json
        NSLog(@"%@", dic);
        //show names catched uin the json

        //set the ids of json  as number of button.tag
        int numberOfButtons = [dic[@"id"] integerValue];
        // show number of button.tag


        if(xPos == 170){

            NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            yPos +=20;
            //create a button
            self.button = [UIButton alloc];
            self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            self.button.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 40, 20);
            button.tag = numberOfButtons;
            //set the button title for the normal state
            [self.button setTitle:[dic objectForKey:@"id"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            //set the button title for when the finger is pressing it down
            [self.button setTitle:[dic objectForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            //add action to capture the button press down event
            [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonIsPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            //add the button to the view
            [sView addSubview:self.button];

            //Button Styles
            yPos += 10;
            test = 50 + yPos;



            //Add the button into array
            [mutableArray addObject:button];
            //show code button


            xPos = 0;
            x = 10;

        }


        if(x == 0){


    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        //adding 10 to change the location of the next button that will be create

        y +=20;
        //create a button
        self.button = [UIButton alloc];
        self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        self.button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 40, 20);
        button.tag = numberOfButtons;
        //set the button title for the normal state
        [self.button setTitle:[dic objectForKey:@"id"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //set the button title for when the finger is pressing it down
        [self.button setTitle:[dic objectForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        //add action to capture the button press down event
        [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonIsPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        //add the button to the view
        [sView addSubview:self.button];

        //Button Styles
        y += 10;





        //Add the button into array
        [mutableArray addObject:button];
        //show code button
       //NSLog(@"%@", mutableArray);

        xPos = 170;

    }

        if (x == 10) {

            x = 0;

        }
        CGSize sViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, test);
        [sView setContentSize:sViewContentSize];
      //NSLog(@"%i", test);
    }

}
```

And here is the Log

```
2017-05-11 10:08:16.589 tentativaJSON[4082:90b] pontos
```

So I want catch the Details of `pontos` but it is showing only it, i need use the values of Id`s and the other informations inside it to do buttons related to it, using this //http://api.iospond.com/api/index.php/GetData I don't get any problem, but if I'm using this //http://blessing.com.br/aplicativos/pontos.php I get this error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, someone can help with it?

Comment: you are getting dictionary in JSN response. so just fetch for key 'pontos'. from here you will get array of dictionary. Remember '{' represents Dictionary while '[' represents Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **GET** :-

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString 
 stringWithFormat:@"http://api.iospond.com/api/index.php/GetData"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:
[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, 
NSData *data, NSError *error) {NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response 
              statusCode] == 200) {

                               NSArray *dict = (NSArray *)str;

                               NSLog(@"Parse here:: %@",dict);

                           }else {
                               NSLog(@"elseelse 
          %@",error.localizedDescription);
                           }
                       }];
```

- Then check you getting array or Dictionary for parsing step by step..

Comment: NSURLConnection deprecated in iOS9

Comment: So using this URL  http://api.iospond.com/api/index.php/GetData I dont have any problem to use my code, and using this way that u show, will I  continue doing the for that I use to create buttons based on the ids of the json?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dic in json
```

will only give you the keys.
To get their values use

```
json[dic]
```

Comment: so I will put like this ? `for (NSDictionary *dic in json[dic])`

Comment: you can do something like: `for (NSDictionary *dic in json) { value = json[dic]}`. and then use value

Comment: That's dont work, it shows an error thats value its undeclared indentifier

Comment: value is a new identifier - you should use a type when you define it, such as `NSDictionary *value = json[dic]`. From then on use value instead of dic such as: `int numberOfButtons = [value[@"id"] integerValue];`

Comment: when I define it as  `NSDictionary *value = json[dic];  ` that show an error too,  ` Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSArray * ' `

Comment: @MatheusRohwedder  NSArray *value = json[dic]; use array because your "pontos" is an array of Dictionaries

Comment: That's won't work too, my code its getting an error that says, Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, and after this stop the execution